# Bug: Interpreting C# code as incorrectly formatted code

Tags: bug, code-formatting, code, formatting

When using the `code format` sometimes the color isn't correct.

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59182545/10899908) the word **`CPerson`** **Blue** is blue instead of **Black**:

[image]

And the `set` is **Blue**, and `get` is *Black*:

[image]

This is a screenshot from Visual Studio of the correct format:

[image]

Comment: Code formatting here is outsourced to Google Prettify. The linked duplicate contains more information, including a description of how to report bugs to Prettify. As for the inconsistent highlighting of get/set, it [looks like this was fixed](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/214), but Stack Exchange probably hasn't upgraded their Prettify version since then.

Comment: I mean, who gets to say which color scheme is "correct" for a given language?

Comment: It isn't the color scheme, @user400654, it's the fact that keywords are not being properly detected and highlighted as such.

Comment: that still sounds like a color scheme

Comment: Why is this downvoted when it is an actual bug (that is not covered by the so-called duplicate)?

Comment: Will Stack Exchange discover that this is an actual bug when this is closed? If this bug has been fixed in the third-party software, then it is Stack Exchange that needs to act. Shouldn't it be tagged with "status-review" or similar?